# Getting Sorted Data from DevExpress-GridControl

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I'm using a DevExpress-GridControl with built-in sorting. When exporting the data to a Report I want to use the sorted data from the grid. The binding-/datasource representing the data stays unsorted.

Is there a way to get the data in a sorted order?

Thanks in advance Tobias

Comment: What part of DevExpress suite you use? ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF..? Do you use ASPxGridViewExporter to export grid data or you made custom XtraReport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this sample will be helpful:
[How to convert an XtraGrid to an XtraReport at runtime](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E108)